# Text Classification using Random Forest in R

Tags: r, random-forest

Hi I'm new to R and want perform text message classification in R. Data contains 2 columns: "type":spam or ham and "message": character. I have performed data cleaning and converted data into Document Term Matrix

`data_dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(corpus, control = list(global = c(2, Inf)))`
Now I want to use the Random forest classification:

```
sms_classifier <- randomForest(x= as.matrix(sms_dtm_train), y= train_data$type, ntree= 10)
```

sms_dtm_train: is the document term matrix of training data
This code is not working. Please tell me what is the problem?
This is the error message i am getting

`Error in randomForest.default(x = as.matrix(sms_dtm_train), y = train_data$type,  : 
  NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 1)
In addition: Warning message:
In storage.mode(x) <- "double" : NAs introduced by coercion`

Comment: Have you checked the documentation?

Comment: Yes I did. But the output of this statement does not give the desired result

Comment: Please show how `sms_dtm_train` and `train_data` look like. Use `str`, for example.

Comment: The issue is resolved. I found an error in the dataset and fixed it. thanks for the help.